# How to containerize a python script from a pulled image from docker hub

Tags: python, docker

First I am very new to docker, so apologies if this doesn't make sense.

This is my situation:

I have a data science/machine learning project in a python script (written in a single .`py` file). I want to containerize this application.

I would need to create a Dockerfile to do that. But since this is a machine learning project, there are a lot of packages that I need to pip install. So I found this Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3, which has miniconda installed, which has the packages that I need.

I pulled this image.

[image]

And now I don't know what to do with it. How do I continue from here. So far, my Dockerfile is empty. How can I use this image as my starting point and perhaps install more modules if needed and then finally, how to containerize my python script based on this modified image?

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a base image using the `FROM` command.

Example:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest
```

You'll want to use the `RUN` command to install dependencies (assuming you need any more,) the `COPY` command to get your `main.py` file into the container, and `CMD` can be used to set a default command to run when the container starts up. Documentation for each of those can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).